# Catch multiple strings by criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to parse this piece of text. First step would be catching all between `[feat]` and linebreak. Second step would be even better to catch all feats and group them by shown date. The text is stored in a variable. Here is an example:

```
## [1.0.0] - 2019-06-28
[feat] - Complete generate pdf refactor

## [1.0.1] - 2019-07-04
[fix] Fixed generate address

[fix] Fixed warrant print

[fix] Fixed note component

## [1.0.2] - 2019-07-05
[feat] Add views as response for production

[feat] Add component 

[fix] Fixed warrant
```

I’ve tried using `[(feat])(.*)/n` and `str.match` but I’m missing something.

Result I'm tring to get would be: 
["Fixed generate address","Add views as response for production", "Add component"]

or even better grouped by date

Comment: Is `[(feat])(.*)/n` supposed to be a regex? Please use [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/zcp9cn/1) to receive an explanation as to what it means. Linebreak is `\n`, not `/n`, `[(feat]` means a single character of either `(`, `f`, `e`, `a`, or `t`. The stray `)` is a syntax error. How exactly have you tried `str.match`? Have you used the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors?

Comment: Use `str.match(/\[feat]\W*(.+)/)[1]` if these strings are standalone. You may just use `/\[feat]\W*(.+)/g` regex with `re.exec(str)` in a loop.

Comment: I have tried using regex101 http://prntscr.com/obo6ll  that's how I got it. Quite new to regex.

Comment: Do you need `["Complete generate pdf refactor","Add views as response for production", "Add component"]` in fact? See https://regex101.com/r/LrbGSB/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes exactly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/\[feat]\W*(.+)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LrbGSB/2). NOTE: if there can only be whitespaces and hyphens between `[feat]` and the data you need to extract you may precise the pattern as

```
/\[feat][\s-]*(.+)/g
        ^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LrbGSB/3) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5Bfeat%5D%5B%5Cs-%5D*(.%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `\[feat]` - a `[feat]` substring
- `\W*` - 0 or more non-word chars
- `[\s-]*` - 0 or more whitespaces or/and hyphens
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars.

JS demo:

```js
var s = "## [1.0.0] - 2019-06-28\n[feat] - Complete generate pdf refactor\n## [1.0.1] - 2019-07-04\n[fix] Fixed generate address\n\n[fix] Fixed warrant print\n\n[fix] Fixed note component\n\n## [1.0.2] - 2019-07-05\n[feat] Add views as response for production\n\n[feat] Add component \n\n[fix] Fixed warrant";
var rx = /\[feat]\W*(.+)/g, m, res=[];
while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```